# Installation of package ‘tidyr’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, tidyr

All my packages are getting updated except tidyr what exactly is the issue im not sure.

```
make: *** [cpp11.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tidyr’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/tidyr’
* restoring previous ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/tidyr’
```

Any suggestion or help is really appreciated

Comment: Sometimes I find restarting R with no packages loaded helps with this error.

Comment: " I find restarting R with no packages"? how can you tell

Comment: If you are using R Studio you can view which packages are loaded in the pane on the right hand side.

Comment: i do use r studio but i update from the terminal